# Font families available in JavaFX 8

Tags: fonts, javafx, font-family

In my JavaFX application, the user will have the possibility to choose the font or font family for displaying the menus, labels, combo boxes, check boxes etc. Where can I find the different font families available for JavaFX 8?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can get the list of installed font families by calling `javafx.scene.text.Font.getFamilies();`.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would attach a CSS sheet to your program, in that case you can set the default font family using .root, something like this;

```
    .root{
    -fx-font-family: "Courier New";
}
```

Here are some examples of some websafe fonts you could use in CSS;

http://www.webdesigndev.com/16-gorgeous-web-safe-fonts-to-use-with-css/

And:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp